# Which norm is greater when exchanging a min operator

Tags: inequality, convex-optimization, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, matrix-norms

Given these two relationships, what is true about them?

$$ (i):  \min_{|| e ||_2 \leq c} |p^H x - e^H x |^2 \geq or \leq | \min_{|| e ||_2 \leq c} p^H x - e^H x |^2 $$

$$ (ii):  \max_{|| e ||_2 \leq c} |p^H x - e^H x |^2 \geq or \leq | \max_{|| e ||_2 \leq c} p^H x - e^H x |^2 $$

where $|| e ||_2 \leq || p ||_2 $, $ e $ is a complex vector and the vectors $ p $, $ x $ are known. Also $ c $ is known.

I have found that under the condition provided $|| e ||_2 \leq || p ||_2 $, then $(i)$ and $(ii)$ hold with equality which to me is somewhat counter-intuitive.

The solution I got for (i) is $ e = \frac{p}{|| p ||_2} c $ and for (ii) is $ e = -\frac{p}{|| p ||_2} c $.

Can anyone explain why the order of the min operator does not matter? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Unless I am missing something the conditions are always true.

Comment: So, you also agree they are equivalent?

Comment: They seem meaningless to me.